# Video.js vertical orientation player

Tags: video.js

I'm a newbie with video.js.

I would like to ask if anybody had tried to resizing the player to play a video in 9:16 (vertical) and fit perfectly the size of the player.

So far it does work but only on Firefox 28.0 not on Chrome and Safari(Mac os) also Chrome, Safari and IE (Win os).

Instead I got the player in vertical but the video is very small and playing in 16:9.

Thank you in advance, I've been reallt stuck on it for too long.
Let me know if you need more details or the whole project.

Best,

Mitch

Comment: An example of what you've tried would help. Are you trying to stretch or rotate a 16:9 video?

Comment: Actually I'm tried to rotate the player, so far this is what I could do. http://www.gutenberg-networks.com/video_newsletter/test_video/issey-miyake.html It works perfectly on Chrome, Safari, Firefox on mac os and also Chrome and Firefox on Win os except IE 9.